# iPhone not detecting NFC tag

Tags: iphone, nfc

I want to be able to open a link on my phone using an NFC tag.

I brought some Timeskey NFC tags to do some tests.

On Android, I have no issue using NFC tools app I can read and write, on iPhone 12 nothing works.

First I tried with an empty tag using [NFC tools](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nfc-tools/id1252962749) and my iPhone never detects the tag to read or write. Then I updated the tag to open a link but nothing happens, I tried with the phone locked and unlocked.

Then I tried with an iPhone 13 and I have the exact same issue, I read some posts but on those phones seems that the NFC can not be disabled, the service is always listening.

I contacted the NFC tag vendor, and they ensure me the tag is working with iPhone, but you know this is this typical product coming from a Chinese factory and no one know how it works in details. The tag type is ISO 14443-3A.

I can not find any information on the Internet to know if there are only some tags compatible with iPhone or if there is some kind of special encoding for iPhone.

Comment: Can you link to the actual tags that you're using? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The NFC tag must be NDEF formatted in order to work with the iPhone.

Also make sure that you do not have a cover on the iPhone preventing the tag from working. I would suggest testing without a cover at first - and make sure to place the tag directly against the antenna on the iPhone.

And yes, only some tags are compatible with iPhone. The tag must be of NFC Forum Tag Type 1-5. This does cover some ISO 14443-3A tags.